# unable to convert SQL query to entity framework vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework

Disclaimer: may be long post

There is a lot of questions like this, and I am not quite happy to join the pack but yet ,
I am having a table which contains several rows and each they have effective dates, my sql query will fetch the latest records based on the effective date

```
select * from TblTaxmasters
```

[image]

i am using this query to get desired result

```
select * FROM (select t1.id,t1.shortcode,t1.rev_no,t1.percentage,t1.effectivedate startdate, isnull(MIN(t2.effectivedate),getdate()+1) as enddate FROM tbltaxmaster t1 LEFT
OUTER JOIN tbltaxmaster t2 on t1.id=t2.id AND t1.effectivedate < t2.effectivedate 
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.shortcode,t1.effectivedate,t1.rev_no,t1.percentage ) tx where '2014-05-01' BETWEEN tx.startdate AND tx.enddate
```

The output is
[image]

now i am trying to convert this query against entity framework dbcontext in vb.net winforms 4.0

this is what i tried

```
Dim tomm = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
Dim mydate = DateTime.Today
Dim tax = (From t In (From t1 In tblTaxmasters
                                    From t2 In tblTaxmasters
                                    Where t1.id = t2.id And t1.effectivedate < t2.effectivedate
                                    Select New With {.id = t1.id, .shortcode = t1.shortcode, .maxdate = t1.effectivedate, .mindate = If(t2.effectivedate.HasValue, t2.effectivedate, tomm), .percentage = t1.percentage, .revno = t1.rev_no})
                                Where mydate >= t.mindate And mydate <= t.maxdate Select New With {t.shortcode, t.id, t.percentage, t.revno}).ToList()
```

and it told me

> nothing

no result , then i tried the same thing with linqpad and it shows query executed successfully but no results. I checked the sql output and here what i get

```
    -- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2014-05-10 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2014-05-09 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @p2 DateTime = '2014-05-09 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[shortcode], [t2].[id], [t2].[percentage], [t2].[rev_no] AS [revno]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[shortcode], [t0].[effectivedate], 
        (CASE 
            WHEN [t1].[effectivedate] IS NOT NULL THEN [t1].[effectivedate]
            ELSE @p0
         END) AS [value], [t0].[percentage], [t0].[rev_no], [t1].[id] AS [id2], [t1].[effectivedate] AS [effectivedate2]
    FROM [tblTaxmaster] AS [t0], [tblTaxmaster] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE (@p1 >= [t2].[value]) AND (@p2 <= [t2].[effectivedate]) AND ([t2].[id] = [t2].[id2]) AND ([t2].[effectivedate] < [t2].[effectivedate2])
```

obviously something

> lost in translation

so anybody can point me which way to move forward.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20444918/2278086)?

Answer (score 0):

@Mark, Thanks for pointing the right direction, actually i have to tweak it with the help of [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/5128240.aspx) link in another forum. But glad both worked out, so here is what i have did finally

```
Dim tax = From c In ctx.tblTaxmasters
                        Group c By c.id Into g = Group
                    Select g.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.effectivedate).FirstOrDefault()


            Dim mytax = tax.ToList()
```

Thanks for the help

Today accidentally when i searched inside [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=linq%20group%20by%20select%20max%20date&emptyWatermark=true&ac=3) there are loads of questions based on the same topic is already available, and most prominent answers are from stack over flow. And it digs deeper than what i thought , it leads me to vb and c# compiler difference of anonymous types the key keyword etc. one surprising fact is that msdn search is spot on than google.